# PL-SQL - Can I pass enum as function argument?

Tags: mysql, function, enums, parameter-passing

I've a field/column named 'type' with enum datatype in my table, I wish to use similar type of parameter for my PL-SQL function.

Can I pass enum as function argument?

I've tried following function (for mySQL) but it does accept enum as function argument/parameter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `save_type` (type('new', 'existing', 'xyz') IN enum)

RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN

RETURN 1;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ENUM type for a function parameter, but you've got the wrong syntax for MySQL.

This works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `save_type` (type enum('new', 'existing', 'xyz'))

RETURNS INTEGER
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

RETURN 1;
END
```

Differences:

- List the enum values after the `enum` keyword.
- There is no option for `IN` versus `OUT` parameter for MySQL stored functions.
- Functions should be declared with one of `DETERMINISTIC`, `NO SQL`, or `READS SQL DATA`.

Answer (score 1):

Function parmameters need to be of MySQL data types. `ENUM` is not supported.

Would like to recommend staying away from `ENUM` altogether. Use separate table for the readable values, so you can change them later if needed without major hassle.